# hear someone cry vs hear someone crying

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, tense-agreement

Last night I heard a lady cry/crying.
My book says the correct answer is cry.
.
Last night I heard a man scream/screaming.
My book says the correct answer is screaming.
.
I couldn't get it.
How do we use these verbs?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct in both situations. It depends on the author's intentions.

Here, "cry" and "crying" are interchangeable, since crying (unless it is to "cry out") is a state that is inherently continuous.

Using "scream" means that the man screamed (i.e. let out one scream), whereas "screaming" means that the man was continuously letting out screams for some period.

Comment: Great answer, but if you find a question worth answering, why not upvote it? That’d be courteous.